# Speeding up CMake rebuild after header change

Tags: cmake, ninja

I have a large project that uses cmake and ninja. There's a couple different releases that I need to regularly build. Building a release takes about 10 minutes. The only difference between the two releases is in one header file. Is it possible for me build both releases at once and get the build time close to 10 minutes?

Comment: Just build them in parallel? This is a pretty broad question, as the answer would depend on specifics of your project, such as where the header resides within your project hierarchy, and what optimization options you are (or are not) currently using.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. The header deals with security and debug code, so while it's not directly referenced, it's used by a lot of the core functionality.